# Find an irrational number whose binary development does not contain strings of $0$s or $1$s of arbitrary length

Tags: number-theory

> Find an irrational number whose binary development does not contain strings of $0$s or $1$s of arbitrary length.

I found it hard to find such an example since the only two digits we can use are $0$ and $1$. How can we construct such an example?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not contain strings of arbitrary length"? It means that its binary expansion has only finitely many digits (but in such a case it would be rational!)?

Comment: @Crostul I mean like strings of $1$s: $11111\ldots$ or $0$s: $00000\ldots$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $0.\overline{10}_2$ and change every $0$ in position $(2n)!$ after the dot with a $1$.

Such binary representation is aperiodic (so it gives an irrational number) and given by a concatenation of $0$, $1$ and $111$ only. Additionally, such number is trascendental, as the sum between $\frac{2}{3}$ and a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number).

Answer (score 2):

Call $a=101$, $b=1001$. Using only these two strings as "digits" write a non-repeating infinite pattern, for example
$$0.abaabaaabaaaab...$$
and then substitute $a=101$, $b=1001$.

Answer (score 1):

The following binary expansion contains no substring $11$ or longer and no substring $000$ or longer:

$$0.01\color{crimson}00101\color{crimson}0010101\color{crimson}001010101\color{crimson}0\ldots$$

It’s not eventually periodic, so it’s irrational.

Comment: Why does this represent an irrational number?

Comment: @Servaes: Because it's not eventually periodic. (I didn’t bother to mention that originally, because I thought it evident.)

Answer (score 1):

Take an irrational number (e.g. $\sqrt 2$) in binary format, and replace each $1$ with the sequence $011$ and each $0$ with the sequence $001$. Then you don't have more than two consecutive $0$'s or $1$'s and the generated number is also irrational (does not have periodic substrings).

Answer (score 1):

The number
$$.1?0?1?0?1?0?\dots$$
contains no string of $0$s or $1$s of length $4$. There are uncountably many ways to give values to the $?$ marks, most of them resulting in irrational numbers.

Better, the [Thue–Morse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) sequence represents an irrational number and has no strings of length $3$:
$$.0110100110010110\dots$$

Or the [Kolakoski sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence) (with $2$s changed to $0$s):
$$.10011010010011011\dots$$